# Google Maps API: Ground overlay positioning

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add a ground overlay to a custom map and have created one successfully using the example at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple.html

My problem is I'm trying to move it somewhere else but my overlay is really stretched whenever I changed the coordinates (I'm virtually guessing). Can anyone help me decipher what coordinates go into the code or have any general tips? The following code from the example asks for 4 values, which one is which?

```
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216,-74.22655),
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941,-74.12544));
```

Comment: post some examples picturing what do you mean by "stretched", values in bounds are: first latlng -> northeast corner, second -> southwest corner, inside latlng: first latitude, second longitude, if u change only one value picture will stretch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216,-74.22655),//South West coordinates
new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941,-74.12544));//North East coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

A bounding box expressed in coordinates, where there is the same difference between the 2 latitudes and between the two longitudes will look distorted at different latitudes because that bounding box covers different areas depending on how far north or south it is. Best solution is not to use groundOverlayWithBounds (which I assume you are using), but to use groundOverlayWithPosition and let google maps take care of the aspect ratio.